# error retrieving parent for item theme.appcompat.light.darkactionbar

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, ide

***error retrieving parent for item Theme.appcompat.light.darkactionbar. Tried all the method like***

- **"File->Import (android-sdk\extras\android\support\v7). Choose "appcompat" Project-> properties->Android. In the section library
  "Add" and choose "appCompat""**
- **"-In Properties -> Android add the library, but uncheck "IsLibrary”.
  -In Android -> Project build tarjet check Android 4.0.
  -In "Java Build Path" -> Order and Export -> Unchecked the .jar library
  -Finally do a “Project -> Clean” both projects  "**
- **You should reinstall your Android Support Library by Android SDK Manager to get the complete android supportV7 library. The
  mediarouter library project dependency on the appcompat library
  project. So,after you have finished Step 1, you can follow Android
  Support Library v7: Error retrieving parent for item to fix this
  problem.**

Still the error is not going...what would be the reason.help me upon this guys

Answer (score 0):

Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar

Its case sensitive

Comment: yes its the same.but the error is not about misspell.every case in actual project is correct.the error is on appcompact v7 which i tried all the method to fix the lib, but still its not getting added.

Answer (score 0):

yes its nothing but we should start migrating from eclipse to android studio because the new api's and lib dependencies are not supporting in eclipse. i had resolved that issue.

you can check on [abhilmohan.blogspot.com](http://abhilmohan.blogspot.com)

Comment: the new API's dependencies are hard to work over in eclipse were as Google has announced their official IDE as ANDROID STUDIO.
After installing our new IDE all the dependency problem were solved regarding app.compact v7 and API 19, 20 and 21. Even our new IDE is literally awesome and it includes a lot of new features. So guys don't wait to get your new IDE. just download as early as possible.